# How to turn multiple groups into a binary grouping?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, analytics

I want to report volumes of 'PINK' vs. all other colors

```
with gumdrops_detail as
(
select 1 as customer_id, 'PINK' as gumdrop_color, 400 as gumdrop_volume from dual union all
select 1 as customer_id, 'PINK' as gumdrop_color, 300 as gumdrop_volume from dual union all
select 1 as customer_id, 'BLUE' as gumdrop_color, 500 as gumdrop_volume from dual union all
select 1 as customer_id, 'BLUE' as gumdrop_color, 600 as gumdrop_volume from dual union all
select 1 as customer_id, 'SNOT' as gumdrop_color, 300 as gumdrop_volume from dual union all
select 1 as customer_id, 'SNOT' as gumdrop_color, 100 as gumdrop_volume from dual union all
select 2 as customer_id, 'PINK' as gumdrop_color, 400 as gumdrop_volume from dual union all
select 2 as customer_id, 'PINK' as gumdrop_color, 300 as gumdrop_volume from dual union all
select 2 as customer_id, 'BLUE' as gumdrop_color, 500 as gumdrop_volume from dual union all
select 2 as customer_id, 'BLUE' as gumdrop_color, 600 as gumdrop_volume from dual union all
select 3 as customer_id, 'SNOT'  as gumdrop_color, 300 as gumdrop_volume from dual union all
select 3 as customer_id, 'ECRU' as gumdrop_color, 100 as gumdrop_volume from dual
)
select distinct customer_id,
       gumdrop_color,
       sum(gumdrop_volume) over (partition by customer_id,
                                              gumdrop_color) as vol_by_color,
       sum(case gumdrop_color
            when 'PINK' then gumdrop_volume
            else             gumdrop_volume
            end) over (partition by customer_id,
                                    gumdrop_color) as vol_by_pink_non_pink 
from gumdrops_detail
order by customer_id
```

### Desired Results

```
ID  COLOR   TOTVOL
1   PINK     700
1   NONPINK 1500
2   PINK     700
2   NONPINK 1100
3   PINK       0 --Its OK if this row doesn't return...
3   NONPINK  400
```

Comment: I don't think "SNOT" is a real color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with gumdrops_detail as
(
 ...
)
select customer_id, B.color,
       sum( decode(B.color,
                   decode(gumdrop_color,'PINK','PINK','NONPINK'), gumdrop_volume, 0))
  from gumdrops_detail,
       (select 'PINK' as color from DUAL union select 'NONPINK' from DUAL) B
 group by customer_id, B.color
 order by customer_id, B.color desc
```

Result:

```
1   PINK    700
1   NONPINK 1500
2   PINK    700
2   NONPINK 1100
3   PINK    0
3   NONPINK 400
```

If ZERO for non existing 'PINK' not required:

```
with gumdrops_detail as
(
 ...
)
select customer_id, decode(gumdrop_color,'PINK','PINK','NONPINK') color,sum(gumdrop_volume)
  from gumdrops_detail
 group by customer_id, decode(gumdrop_color,'PINK','PINK','NONPINK')
 order by 1,2 desc
```

P.S.: `decode(B.color,decode(gumdrop_color,'PINK','PINK','NONPINK'),gumdrop_volume, 0)` can be represented as:

```
case B.color
when (
      case gumdrop_color when 'PINK' then 'PINK'
                         else 'NONPINK'
      end
     )
then gumdrop_volume
else 0
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient solution, but it's easy to understand.

```
with gumdrops_detail as
(
........
)
select * from (
select customer_id as id,
       'PINK' as color,
       sum(case gumdrop_color when 'PINK' then gumdrop_volume else 0 end) as total_volume
from   gumdrops_detail
group by customer_id
union all
select customer_id as id,
       'NON-PINK' as color,
       sum(case gumdrop_color when 'PINK' then 0 else gumdrop_volume end) as total_volume
from   gumdrops_detail
group by customer_id
)
order by id, case color when 'PINK' then 0 else 1 end
;

        ID COLOR                               TOTAL_VOLUME
---------- -------- ---------------------------------------
         1 PINK                                         700
         1 NON-PINK                                    1500
         2 PINK                                         700
         2 NON-PINK                                    1100
         3 PINK                                           0
         3 NON-PINK                                     400

 6 rows selected
```

A more advanced (and perhaps more efficient) solution uses `unpivot` - available since Oracle version 11.

```
select id, color, total_volume from (
select customer_id as id,
       sum(case gumdrop_color when 'PINK' then gumdrop_volume else 0 end) as pink,
       sum(case gumdrop_color when 'PINK' then 0 else gumdrop_volume end) as non_pink
from   gumdrops_detail
group by customer_id
)
unpivot (total_volume for color in (pink as 'PINK', non_pink as 'NON_PINK'))
order by id, case color when 'PINK' then 0 else 1 end
;
```

Comment: Row with zero for customer_id=3/PINK can not be in result of your current query

Comment: Please bring back your earlier proposed solutions using analytics...I found them intriguing...

Comment: @Mike - you are correct, I was too lazy - I copied the solution but forgot to delete the row from the output. I will fix it now. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: @zundarz - You can always recover what was edited by clicking on the "edited..." link below the Answer (or below the Question as the case may be). In this case, I compared the plans. The optimizer cost of both my old solutions was 31, while this new (and much simpler) solution has an optimizer cost of 26, so it's more efficient by about 20%. (Mike's solution has an optimizer cost of 51, but it was still his solution that made me look at the problem again and realize there's a much simpler solution). Also, please note my old solution used UNION ALL and PIVOT respectively, no analytic functions.

Comment: @Mike - sorry, I re-read your solution and of course you are 100% right. I stopped reading after the first solution... :-(   I will just roll back to my original solution but only because it shows different approaches; in reality I should delete my answer altogether because your solution is the best.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to split pink vs non-pink into separate columns then this 
query may be suitable.

```
select distinct customer_id,
       sum(gumdrop_volume) over (partition by customer_id) as cust_volume,

       sum(case gumdrop_color 
            when 'PINK' then gumdrop_volume
            else 0
            end) over (partition by customer_id) as pink_v,

       sum(case gumdrop_color 
            when 'PINK' then 0
            else gumdrop_volume
            end) over (partition by customer_id) as non_pink_v
from gumdrops_detail  
order by customer_id
```

**Results**

```
 ID   VOL  PINK_V  NON-PINK_V
     1 2200   700        1500
     2 1800   700        1100
     3  400     0         400
```